# datetime conversion fails in OPENJSON function

Tags: sql-server, json, azure-sql-database

I am using a json coming from logicapp events which has datetime properties in below format

> ```
> "startTime": "2017-07-12T17:14:16.0500772Z",
> "endTime": "2017-07-12T17:14:17.2939322Z",
> ```

in a stored proc with the **OPENJSON Sql function**.
When I execute the 'SELECT' with this function it fails with this error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 33 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

My observation has been that OPENJSON fails to convert the millisec part after the 3rd digit.

**Question**
Has anyone seen such a problem with OPENJSON SQL function?

Comment: This is unfortunate because the string is 100% compliant with the ISO standard... But what does Microsoft know about standards? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I am having inconsistent problems with type conversion using OPENJSON.  In my case I am getting strange errors converting numeric strings to FLOAT and DECIMAL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `DateTime2`, you should have no issue

**Example**

```
select AsDT2 = try_convert(datetime2,'2017-07-12T17:14:16.0500772Z')
      ,AsDT  = try_convert(datetime, '2017-07-12T17:14:16.0500772Z')
```

**Returns**

```
AsDT2                         AsDT
2017-07-12 17:14:16.0500772   NULL   --<< Fails DateTime conversion
```

**The Actual Conversion**

```
Declare @JSON varchar(max) = '{"startTime": "2017-07-12T17:14:16.0500772Z","endTime": "2017-07-12T17:14:17.2939322Z"}'

SELECT * FROM  
 OPENJSON (@JSON )  
WITH (   
              startTime  datetime2 '$.startTime',  
              endTime    datetime2 '$.endTime'
 )
```

**See It In Action [dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d66abc5c7328e868826a92d8e31f5eea)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @TusharJ Happy to help

Comment: My friends how to insert if datetime2 could be Null value?

Comment: @GSandro_StrongsNot sure I understand your question, but take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=58292fede3b5cee1338f1c92e39342ca